# Treat float as int in javascript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bit-shift, webm

I just started building a javascript webm decoder.
For one of the binary operations, I need to be able to get 8 bytes and mask out 1 byte. Is there a cleaner way of doing this? Currently I'm getting 2 ints, masking, then or-ing them back together. If I get a float64 the bitwise operations won't work correctly.

Essentially the operation is to mask off the amount bits from the left side as the amount of bytes read in.

https://github.com/Matroska-Org/ebml-specification/blob/master/specification.markdown

Check out section on VINT.

```
        case 8:
            //Largest allowable integer in javascript is 2^53-1 so gonna have to use one less bit for now
            raw = dataview.getFloat64(offset);
            var firstInt = dataview.getUint32(offset) & 0x000FFFFF;
            var secondInt = dataview.getUint32(offset + 4);
            vint_data = (firstInt << 8) | secondInt;
            break;
```

Comment: Read them as two sets of 4 bytes and then operate on them as 32-bit numbers.

Comment: Thats what it is currently doing

Comment: *"...and mask out 1 byte"*: can you complete the code with that part? Or do you speak of the two bytes that are shifted out of `firstInt`? It also seems that the `|` will really combine 2 bytes from both arguments, both having bits in those two bytes. Is that what you want?

Comment: What I need is this:

0000 0001  xxxx xxxx  xxxx xxxx  xxxx xxxx  xxxx xxxx  xxxx xxxx  xxxx xxxx  xxxx xxxx 

Where you mask out the first 7 0's and the 1, so total 8. So read 64 bits and mask out the left most 8 bits, and interpret this as an integer. The x's are supposed to be the valid data

Comment: What are you going to do with the value? How do you intent to keep it? You want to hold 56 bit of data, but a float can only take up to 53 bit.

Comment: It's to know how many bytes to read after that. And yes the 53 bit thing is also a problem. I masked out a little bit more for now